# Automator folder action leaves files ghosted in Finder

Tags: finder, automator

This is my action:

[image]

When I drop an item in `~/Downloads`, this happens:

[image]

I've redacted other files in that pic - they are black ink and I can do normal things with them in Finder. The `pic-of-bigmac.jpeg` item is greyed-out (ghosted) just added to the folder after I created the automator action, but I can't do anything with it . It stays like that for ages. Maybe it stops being ghosted after an hour but who would want to wait that long?  What have I done wrong?

And where are automator actions stored, as it is not clear?  I mean this one `downloads-run-script` (.automator I suspect)

Comment: There is nothing in your **Automator** _workflow_ that could have done this. There is no relation whatsoever to the running of the _Folder Action workflow_ and the presence of and or it being greyed out in **Finder**. BTW **Automator** _actions_ are in: `/System/Library/Automator`

Comment: `$ find /System/Library/Automator -name "downloads-run-script*"` yields nothing.

Comment: **Automator** _actions_ are stored  exactly where I said they were. In other words, the file that you  see in your _workflow_ of the **Run Shell Script** _action_ is `/System/Library/Automator/Run Shell Script.action`.  You did after all ask, "And where are automator actions stored, as it is not clear?".  That said, if what you're really looking for is the **Automator** _Folder Action workflow_ you created, that typically is saved in: `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions`

Comment: `~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions` .. thanks